# "Mi/ti/ecc. garba" si usa spesso come sinonimo di "mi/ti/ecc. piace"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Di recente mi sono imbattuto nella frase "[questa cosa] mi garba di più". Era la prima volta che vedevo il verbo "garbare"; sembra significare su per giù lo stesso che "piacere". Questo verbo si utilizza spesso nell'italiano parlato? E porta una qualche sfumatura che lo differenzi da "piacere"?

Comment: Solo in Toscana, penso.

Comment: Da notare l'aggettivo "garbato"  che ha il significato di  "educato",  "di buone maniere".  Oppure  "sgarbato" = maleducato.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questo lungo articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca  disquisisce sul fatto che ***[garbare](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/garbare-toscano-italiano)*** sia un’espressione  regionale  toscana o  della lingua italiana. La conclusione sembra essere più a favore della prima ipotesi. Personalmente l’ho sempre sentita usare soltanto in Toscana o da toscani.

Il significato è:

> nella lessicografia è registrato nel significato di 'piacere, andare a genio, riuscire gradito' detto di oggetti o persone.

Concludendo:

> siamo di fronte a una forma che, da un lato, fa parte a pieno titolo del patrimonio storico della tradizione lessicale italiana, anche se da alcune notazioni sulla limitazione d'uso sembra ormai inserito in un processo tendente alla marginalità; dall'altro si mostra elemento vitale e persistente del linguaggio fiorentino in particolare, e toscano in generale, e come tale è riconosciuto dai parlanti della regione, tanto da essere censurato nel passaggio all'italiano standard, laddove per i non toscani può essere avvertito invece come un preziosismo se non un arcaismo o un'affettazione.

Answer (score 2):

"Garbare" è senz'altro da ritenersi un toscanismo, ovvero un termine regionale ammesso nella lingua parlata in Toscana e comunque compreso in tutta Italia ma non accettabile nello scritto se non in comunicazioni di tipo informale fra conoscenti.
Per il significato è un sinonimo pieno di "piacere".

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!